# cocoa + context sensitive menu on NSTableView with multiple rows selected

Tags: cocoa, contextmenu

i am having a problem displaying context sensitive menu on control click on a tableview when multiple rows are selected.
Its working fine when a single row is selected and then control clicked on it. 
The way i am implementing this is shown below:

```
-(void)doSingleClick  
{  
    NSLog(@"single clicked");

    if([[NSApp currentEvent] modifierFlags] & NSControlKeyMask)
    {

        NSLog(@"control clicked.......");

        [NSMenu popUpContextMenu:[self showContextMenu] withEvent:[NSApp currentEvent] forView:tableView];

        return;
    }

}
```

and showContextMenu function returns a NSMenu object.

I am dong it this way as my table view for some strange reason does not recognize mouseDown or mouseUp or menuForEvent events.

the problem with the above code segment is, when multiple rows are selected and control clicked, it does not recognize the control click and does not go into that loop and hence not displaying the context menu.

Please suggest me a mechanism to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: How does `-(void)doSingleClick` get called?  This is likely the reason for the problem.

Comment: [tableView setAction:@selector(doSingleClick)]; in awakeFromNib
So whenever there is a single click it gets called

Answer (score 18):

I don't recommend the approach that is given in the answers above. Instead, look at the "[DragNDropOutlineView](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/DragNDropOutlineView/Introduction/Intro.html)" example in Leopard and higher. That, and the release notes, give a proper way to implement contextual menus for a single row, or multiple rows. This includes having AppKit automatically do the proper highlighting.

corbin dunn
(NSTableView Software Engineer)

Comment: **In a nutshell:** assign a delegate to your NSMenu, and implement a delegate method such as `menuNeedsUpdate(_:)`. It'll allow you to set the menu's items to whatever you'd like, anytime the menu is shown. **Also,** if you empty the menu out, that will cancel its display.

Answer (score 1):

> i hve tableviewcontroller class which is a subclass of NSTableView.

That's very bad naming and suggests that you are not architecting your application properly. Views aren't controllers. Keep them separate.

> but this class in which i implemented menuForEvent method but its not getting called for some reason.

Did you make your table view an instance of this class in Interface Builder? If not, your instance is still an NSTableView, and the subclass you wrote is what [Ian Hickson might call](http://www.webstandards.org/2009/05/13/interview-with-ian-hickson-editor-of-the-html-5-specification/) “a work of fiction”.

Answer (score 1):

Corbin's answer is the best one here.

[link text](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/DragNDropOutlineView/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the action method is called when multiple rows are selected.

What would probably be a lot easier would be to override the `menuForEvent:` method in `NSTableView`. You'd have to create a subclass of `NSTableView` to do this, but it would be a cleaner solution.

You could also create an informal protocol (a category on `NSObject`) and have the `NSTableView` delegate return the appropriate menu.

```
@interface NSObject (NSCustomTableViewDelegate)

- (NSMenu *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView menuForEvent:(NSEvent *)event;

@end

@implementation NSObject (NSCustomTableViewDelegate)

- (NSMenu *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView menuForEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    return nil;
}

@end
```

And in your `NSTableView` subclass:

```
- (NSMenu *)menuForEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    return [[self delegate] tableView:self menuForEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: i hve tableviewcontroller class which is a subclass of NSTableView. but this class in which i implemented menuForEvent method but its not getting called for some reason. please can u tell me where i am doing wrong??

Thanks

Comment: What else have you implemented that would intercept a click? It's possible this isn't getting called because the click is being intercepted elsewhere.

Comment: nothing else. i have implemented 
[tableView setAction:@selector(doSingleClick)]; in awakeFromNib and
[tableView setDoubleAction:@selector(doSingleClick)]; in awakeFromNib to intercept double clicks.
I tried using mouseDown and other mouse events without these methods but they were not getting called or the app is not recognizing these events.
But the thing is even if there are multiple rows selected, and then i control click, it is going into doSingleClick func but not into the loop which is for control click.

thanks

Comment: sorry it is [tableView setDoubleAction:@selector(doDoubleClick)]; for doubleclick operation.

Comment: If all you want to do is display a menu (i.e. you don't need to do anything when the user single clicks), I'd recommend implementing `menuForEvent:` and _not_ assigning any selector to the table view's `action`. Otherwise, I'd try and figure out why your `if` statement isn't working. Have you tried comparing the result like this: `([[NSApp currentEvent] modifierFlags] & NSControlKeyMask) != 0`? I've had issues with that before. Also, try setting a breakpoint and check the `modifierFlags` in the debugger to make sure it's the event you expect.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the comments. The point is for some strange reason that i dont know,my app is not able to recognise the menuforevent method( i.e. it is not going into that func and i did that without assigning any selector to the table view's action. ).
the if statement is working because if only one file is selected, it is showing me the context sensitive menu.

Thanks